# Android detect when user swipe is finished

Tags: android

I am using a viewPager to let the user swipe. I know about the OnPageChangeListener but it doesn't seem to have a listener when the page is *standing still* i.e. the page has locked into it's new position.

Anyone know any tricks to fire off an event when this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        Log.i(null, "SCROLL_STATE_IDLE");
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this method is in addOnPageChangeListener in ViewPager